# How to convert a image into Base64 string without compressing the image?

Tags: java, android, image

Every time I update the same picture the image quality has been decreased by image compression method.

```
 public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return base64Image;
}
```

I don't want to compress image again and again. Please suggest something.

Comment: what does `"update the same picture"` mean?

Comment: Remove this line bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);

Comment: No it hasn't. PNG compression is lossless.

Comment: @RakshitNawani If you remove that line there would be nothing in the `ByteArrayOutputStream` at all.

Comment: does "update the same picture" means that your'e doing it in a loop? please clarify your question @sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all using PNG compression will not lose image quality.

If you want to get the bytes without compression anyway, you can try the following:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight());
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
byte[] data = buffer.array();
```

To get `Bitmap` back from byte array:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
return bitmap;
```

Comment: What's **width** and **height** in this line? `Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);`

Comment: Obviously, they represent the width and height of the resulting bitmap. And they should be known in advance because the pixels are stored in one dimensional array.

Comment: I tried that, I gave width and height of my imageView, but its not displaying the image only grey area is shown.

Comment: When I'm using compress method it is working fine but image smaller than the actual image which was encoded, I want same size.

Comment: You cannot give arbitrary values of width and height. You must use the same width and height of the original bitmap.